# Looking for a sequential pattern with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a df as

```
  Id  Event SeqNo
   1    A    1
   1    B    2
   1    C    3
   1    ABD  4
   1    A    5
   1    C    6
   1    A    7
   1    CDE  8
   1    D    9
   1    B    10 
   1    ABD  11
   1    D    12
   1    B    13
   1    CDE  14
   1    A    15
```

I am looking for a pattern "ABD followed by CDE without having event B in between them "
For example, The output of this df will be :

```
 Id  Event SeqNo
 1    ABD  4
 1    A    5
 1    C    6
 1    A    7
 1    CDE  8
```

This pattern can be followed multiple times for a single ID and I want find the list of all those IDs and their respective count (if possible).

Comment: "This pattern can be followed multiple times for a single ID and I want find the list of all those IDs" - this means you want the list of all IDs for which such pattern appears? So you don't need the actual pattern found, or the number of patterns found per id?

Comment: Also can one pattern have different IDs?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I just updated it on the question. My primary objective is to get the list of all Ids.If i can get the count it's even much better for me.
There are multiple ID(thousands) in the dataset. I am only interested in the ID which is following this specific pattern.

Comment: Is it possible ot have multiple `ABD`s before one `CDE`?

Comment: @Jondiedoop yes. ABD can occur multiple times before CDE. For example 
ABD, C, A, ABD, ABD, CDE. for me it's just one count.

Comment: I updated my solution per your output request, please let me know if it helps

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one with some scaling trickery and leveraging convolution to find the required pattern -

```
# Get the col in context and scale it to the three strings to form an ID array
a = df['Event']
id_ar = (a=='ABD') + 2*(a=='B') + 3*(a=='CDE')

# Mask of those specific strings and hence extract the corresponding masked df
mask = id_ar>0
df1 = df[mask]

# Get pattern col with 1s at places with the pattern found, 0s elsewhere
df1['Pattern'] = (np.convolve(id_ar[mask],[9,1],'same')==28).astype(int)

# Groupby Id col and sum the pattern col for final output
out = df1.groupby(['Id'])['Pattern'].sum()
```

That `convolution` part might be a bit tricky. The idea there is to use `id_ar` that has values of `1`, `2` and `3` corresponding to strings `'ABD'`,'`'B'` and `'CDE'`. We are looking for `1` followed by `3`, so using the convolution with a kernel `[9,1]` would result in `1*1 + 3*9 = 28` as the convolution sum for the window that has `'ABD'` and then `'CDE'`. Hence, we look for the conv. sum of `28` for the match. For the case of `'ABD'` followed by '`'B'` and then `'CDE'`, conv. sum would be different, hence would be filtered out.

Sample run -

1) Input dataframe :

```
In [377]: df
Out[377]: 
   Id Event SeqNo
0   1     A     1
1   1     B     2
2   1     C     3
3   1   ABD     4
4   1     B     5
5   1     C     6
6   1     A     7
7   1   CDE     8
8   1     D     9
9   1     B    10
10  1   ABD    11
11  1     D    12
12  1     B    13
13  2     A     1
14  2     B     2
15  2     C     3
16  2   ABD     4
17  2     A     5
18  2     C     6
19  2     A     7
20  2   CDE     8
21  2     D     9
22  2     B    10
23  2   ABD    11
24  2     D    12
25  2     B    13
26  2   CDE    14
27  2     A    15
```

2) Intermediate filtered o/p (look at column `Pattern` for the presence of the reqd. pattern) :

```
In [380]: df1
Out[380]: 
   Id Event SeqNo  Pattern
1   1     B     2        0
3   1   ABD     4        0
4   1     B     5        0
7   1   CDE     8        0
9   1     B    10        0
10  1   ABD    11        0
12  1     B    13        0
14  2     B     2        0
16  2   ABD     4        0
20  2   CDE     8        1
22  2     B    10        0
23  2   ABD    11        0
25  2     B    13        0
26  2   CDE    14        0
```

3) Final o/p :

```
In [381]: out
Out[381]: 
Id
1    0
2    1
Name: Pattern, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a solution based on the assumption that anything other than `ABD`,`CDE` and `B` is irrelevant to or solution. So I get rid of them first by a filtering operation.

Then, what I want to know if there is an ABD followed by a CDE without a B in between. I shift the `Events` column by one in time (note this doesn't have to be a 1 step in units of `SeqNo`).

Then I check every column of the new df whether `Events==ABD` **and** `Events_1_Step==CDE` meaning that there wasn't a `B` in between, but possibly other stuff like `A` or `C` or even nothing. This gets me a list of booleans for every time I have a sequence like that. If I sum them up, I get the count.

Finally, I have to make sure these are all done at `Id` level so use `.groupby`.

**IMPORTANT:** This solution is assumed that your df is sorted by `Id` first and then by `SeqNo`. If not, please do so.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv")
df2 = df[df["Event"].isin(["ABD", "CDE", "B"])]
df2.loc[:,"Event_1_Step"] = df2["Event"].shift(-1)
df2.loc[:,"SeqNo_1_Step"] = df2["SeqNo"].shift(-1)
for id, id_df in df2.groupby("Id"):
    print(id) # Set a counter object here per Id to track count per id
    id_df = id_df[id_df.apply(lambda x: x["Event"] == "ABD" and x["Event_1_Step"] == "CDE", axis=1)]
    for row_id, row in id_df.iterrows():
        print(df[(df["Id"] == id) * df["SeqNo"].between(row["SeqNo"], row["SeqNo_1_Step"])])
```

Comment: I like your idea to filter out other patterns. I am thinking if i count the successive occurrence of  ABD and CDE it will work.
 df2.groupby('id')['Event'].agg(''.join).str.count('ABDCDE ').It will give me the count of times these pattern occur successively.

Comment: basically, every row if `id_df.iterrows()` is a pattern. I would simply add a [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object right under that for loop, whose keys initialized by `df['Id'].unique().values`

Answer (score -1):

You could use this:

```
s = (pd.Series(
np.select([df['Event'] == 'ABD', df['Event'] =='B', df['Id'] != df['Id'].shift()],

                         [True, False, False], default=np.nan))
.ffill()
.fillna(False)
.astype(bool))
corr = (df['Event'] == "CDE") & s
corr.groupby(df['Id']).max()
```

Using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to create a column which has `True` if `Event == 'CDE"` and `False` for `B` or at the start of a new `Id`. By the forward filling using [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html). You have for every value whether `ABD` or `B` was last.  Then you can check if it is True where the value is `CDE`. You could then use [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to check whether it is `True` for any value per `Id`.

Which for

```
   Id  Event SeqNo
   1    A    1
   1    B    2
   1    C    3
   1    ABD  4
   1    A    5
   1    C    6
   1    A    7
   1    CDE  8
   1    D    9
   1    B    10 
   1    ABD  11
   1    D    12
   1    B    13
   1    CDE  14
   1    A    15
   2    B    16
   3    ABD  17
   3    B    18
   3    CDE  19
   4    ABD  20
   4    CDE  21
   5    CDE  22
```

Outputs:

```
Id
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output and the true's and false's don't match up to start and stop appropriately.